# Laravel 5.5 cannot disable VerifyCsrfToken check

Tags: php, laravel, phonegap

I've been looking at the docs:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf#csrf-excluding-uris

When I post from a different domain to a controller route (/create-order), which I added to the $except array I keep getting 302 found status codes.

I need to do an ajax post from a PhoneGap app to the app server.
(Unless I can get a token in the app that is valid on the server).

So create-order is added to $except,
I post from the App to create-order,
I get the 302.

Am I missing something?

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as Middleware;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        '*'
    ];
}
```

EDIT2:

This is what I want:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as Middleware;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        //
    ];

    public function __construct(Application $app, Encrypter $encrypter) {
        parent::__construct($app, $encrypter);

        $header = $this->getallheaders();

        if (isset($header['Authority']) && $header['Authority'] == 'somesecretcode') {
            $this->except[] = 'create-order';
        }
    }


    protected function getallheaders()
    {
        $headers = [];
        foreach ($_SERVER as $name => $value)
        {
            if (substr($name, 0, 5) == 'HTTP_')
            {
                $headers[str_replace(' ', '-', ucwords(strtolower(str_replace('_', ' ', substr($name, 5)))))] = $value;
            }
        }
        return $headers;
    }
}
```

Comment: show the code ..

Comment: i edited the code show what i have and what i want to do

Comment: The code looks alright .. did you check this on Postman to see if this returns any errors

Comment: I found the problem...i had public function store(FormRequest $orderRequest) instead of public function store(Request $orderRequest)